# Symfony2: $form->isValid() is always true

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have problem with form validation in Symfony2:

## part of form class:

```
class CompanyType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
        $builder
            ->add('name', 'text',array("label"=> "Nazwa",'max_length' => 255, 'required'=>true))
            ->add('url', 'url',array("label"=> "Adres strony",'max_length' => 255, 'required'=>true))
            ->add('logo', 'file',array("label"=> "Logo",'max_length' => 255))
            ->add('Dodaj', 'submit');
    }
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver){
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Diliges\DiligesBundle\Entity\Company',
            'error_bubbling' => true
        ));
    }
}
```

## part of Controller method:

```
public function addAction(Request $request){
        $company = new Company();
        $form = $this->createForm(new CompanyType(), $company);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {

            try{
                $company->setActive(false);
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('add_company_thx'));
            }catch(PDOException $e){

            }

        }
        ...
```

## Company entity

```
properties:
        name:
          - NotBlank: ~
          - MinLength: 3
        url:
          - NotBlank: ~
```

Im trying, and trying, and still $form->isValid() return true, always. Even when I submit empty form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must have your validation configuration in the wrong spot.  Look at the docs for where the yml config is placed.  [Basics of Validation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#the-basics-of-validation)

They put the config file in `src/Acme/BlogBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml`.  Also, your format of the config is not correct.  You are missing the entity definition.

```
Diliges\DiligesBundle\Entity\Company:
    properties:
        name:
          - NotBlank: ~
          - MinLength: 3
        url:
          - NotBlank: ~
```

Another option that could be making this not work is if you have enabled a different kind of validation (like annotations). Make sure yml is enabled

Comment: Nice! Thanks, it works! in app/confi/config.yml i had 'validation:      { enable_annotations: true }' and should be 'validation:      { enabled: true }'.

Comment: @unbreak : What you have made will just disable annotations as in [the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#validation) and this may mean that you have a problem in your annotations.